# How to convert dates from varchar to datetime2 in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-server-2016

How can I convert these kind of date values from varchar to datetime2?

```
WITH dates AS (
SELECT '6.7.2012' AS dtm
UNION 
SELECT '13.2.2012' AS dtm
UNION
SELECT '3.12.2012' AS dtm
UNION 
SELECT '20.11.2012' AS dtm
)
SELECT CAST(dtm as datetime2) FROM dates
;
```

This results in an error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`try_convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) instead of `cast`:

```
WITH dates AS (
SELECT '6.7.2012' AS dtm
UNION 
SELECT '13.2.2012' AS dtm
UNION
SELECT '3.12.2012' AS dtm
UNION 
SELECT '20.11.2012' AS dtm
)
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetime2, dtm, 104) FROM dates
;
```

Results:

```
13.02.2012 00:00:00
20.11.2012 00:00:00
03.12.2012 00:00:00
06.07.2012 00:00:00
```

**Note:** try_convert was introduced in 2012 version, for earlier versions you need to use [`convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), risking an exception if the varchar value can't be converted using the specified style.