# convert varchar yyyy-mm-dd T hh:mm to datetime2 in sql server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, format

If the varchar is 2021-08-15T14:00:06Z format, I can convert it with the following code

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, '2021-08-15T14:00:06Z')
```

Result: 2021-08-15 14:00:06.0000000

If the data format is yyyy-mm-dd T hh:mm

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, '2021-08-15T14:03')
```

Result:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Question: how to convert varchar(50): yyyy-mm-dd T hh:mm to datetime2: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000

varchar(50): '2021-08-15T14:03'
Expect result: datetime2:  2021-08-15 14:03:00.000

Comment: This link could help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41740356/how-to-convert-dates-from-varchar-to-datetime2-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just another option if the format is `yyyy-MM-dd-THH:mm`, you can simply concat the seconds.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, '2021-08-15T14:03'+':00')
```

**Results**

```
2021-08-15 14:03:00.0000000
```

Comment: Hi Join, If I have date column in a table, I still get error message when convert this Colum from  Varchar(50) to datetime2. SELECT CONVERT(Open_Date, +':00') from tableA. (Open_Date is a column name in tableA) SQL version:Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Comment: @Anson Being a varchar, I suspect bogus data.   rather than convert use try_convert(datetime2, open_date + ':00')   To identify the bogus data  try SELECT * from YOURTABLE WHERE try_convert(datetime2, open_date + ':00') is null

Comment: @Anson Being a varchar, I suspect bogus data.   rather than convert use try_convert(datetime2, open_date + ':00')   To identify the bogus data  try SELECT * from YOURTABLE WHERE try_convert(datetime2, open_date + ':00') is null

Comment: Hi John,  SELECT try_CONVERT(Open_Date, +':00') from tableA works. THanks

Answer (score 1):

the format is close enough to ISO8601 that it's probably easiest to use that...

```
declare @somedate char(16) = '2021-08-15T14:03';
select convert(datetime2, @somedate + ':00', 126);
```

Alternatively just cut out the "T"...

```
declare @somedate char(16) = '2021-08-15T14:03';
select convert(datetime2, replace(@somedate, 'T', ' '), 120);
```